# how to logout a user when a user open our django web application in new tab as an online banking website

Tags: javascript, django

I want to implement a logic when say my application url is xyz.com suppose a user is login in my application xyz.com and when the same user opens the same application in new tab of same browser i want to logout that user which generally happens in banking websites.

I have been using this javascript along with sessionStorage concept, i am calling from a central code behind page when some one is login the javascript method is called with true parameter and it check with the session variable which is set to 1 for each new tab opened
so whenever a user is logged in and a new tab it gets logout
All is working fine, just a little issue is there when i hold ctrl button and open a new tab by clicking on any link of the application the sessionStorage variable in the new tab holds the last tab value, here is where i am facing the problem.

How to resolve this? i cant disable or stop the ctrl button in the application as it is prohibited to do so.

```
function MultiTabLogOut(strLoginFlag)
{
    alert(strLoginFlag);
    if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
        sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
        }
   else{
        sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
if(sessionStorage.clickcount<2 &&strLoginFlag =='true'){
    alert('You cant open the application in different tab of same browser!Kindly login 
    again!');
        window.location.href='/_layouts/SignOut.aspx';
}
   }
```

Comment: That’s a fundamentally flawed requirement, because that’s not how browsers work. You either remember the login or you don’t. If you do remember it, it shouldn’t matter to you that the user uses multiple tabs. One way to restrict the login to a single tab would be to have a completely Javascript-driven website which keeps the login information in a variable and doesn’t write it to any storage. But that would probably require rewriting your entire architecture.

Comment: Also, "You cant open the application in different tab of same browser! Kindly login again!" seems like a downright user-hostile requirement. Why _couldn't_ you do that?